# dygraphs for data with in Day-Format?

Tags: r, dygraphs

it is possible to use the package dygraphs with my data in the format day:

```
Day            KP1         KP2       KP3
02.01.2007   12345        54564      5156156
03.01.2007
```

I have tried a lot to convert the day to format for dygraphs, but it doesn't work. For example this one:

```
 Data$Day <- strptime(myData2[,1],format="%d.%m.%Y")
 Data <- xts(Data[,1], order.by = myData[,1])
```

My question is: Is it possible to use dygraphs for data which is in the day-format?

Thank a. Greets R007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
Data <- read.table(text="
Day            KP1         KP2       KP3
02.01.2007   12345        54564      5156156
03.01.2007   10346        50565      5156140
04.01.2007    9346        44565      5156140",
  header = TRUE)

Data$Day <- strptime(Data[,1],format="%d.%m.%Y")
Data <- xts(Data[,2:4], order.by = Data[,1])

dygraph(data=Data)
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works. But in my example I read the data from a database, it doesn't work. For what is the 2:4 in the line with xts(..). Is it for the number of the fact-columns?

Comment: well you have to make a reproducible example! And yes 2:4 is referring to column numbers

Comment: what do you mean by: no it works? it's working or not?